# Android Gallery App - unable to select image due to no input

Tags: android, gallery, image

I am currently working on an application that lets users upload pictures by selecting them in the android gallery. This seems to work across most android phones however there are some issues with certain ones. On an  LG Optimus Elite when the gallery is loaded to select the image it does not accept any touch. I can see the pictures and gallery however I cannot not select anything. It is almost as if it is frozen. There is nothing I can do at this point, not even press go back button.

Here is my code that launches the gallery:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
i.setType("image/*");
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_GALLERY_PICTURE);
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this
to open gallery

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

   startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond but I was able to fix the problem using your method.